# Hard Drive Error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I am using Fedora 23, and am getting this error while installing or updating and package. My log from "/var/log/messages" is...

```
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1.00: error: { UNC }
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 57 ba 7f 80 00 00 08 00
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1471840128
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1: EH complete
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
May 27 14:39:48 jackson kernel: ata1.00: cmd 25/00:08:80:7f:ba/00:00:57:00:00/e0 tag 6 dma 4096 in#012         res 51/40:08:80:7f:ba/00:00:57:00:00/e0 Emask 0x9 (media error)
```

Here you can find my Hard Drive Details(`fdisk -l` output)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8ae3e9d8

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048     718847     716800  350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *        718848  209819647  209100800 99.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        209819648  210843647    1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda4        210847742 1953523711 1742675970  831G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        210847744  630278143  419430400  200G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6        630280192 1049710591  419430400  200G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       1049712640 1469143039  419430400  200G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       1469145088 1888575487  419430400  200G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       1888577536 1892673535    4096000    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda10      1892675584 1893650431     974848  476M 83 Linux
/dev/sda11      1893652480 1953523711   59871232 28.6G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Here you can see one more error that is notifying me that my partition 4 does not start on physical sector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get a new hard drive, and clone your this drive to the new drive before your problem gets worse.  If it can't re-allocate a bad sector its used up the spares.  I don't know how many of these you have in your log file for different sectors, but your hard drive is on its way to failure.  It might not be dead for 6 or more months but when it dies all not backed up data is gone.

Comment: Thanks for help and finally I scan whole drive, it tool almost 5 hrs,
and result is 


`[root@jackson jackson]# badblocks -sv /dev/sda`
`Checking blocks 0 to 976762583`
`Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): 735920064one, 2:32:22 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)`
`735920065one, 2:32:25 elapsed. (1/0/0 errors)`
`735920066one, 2:32:59 elapsed. (2/0/0 errors)`
`735920067one, 2:33:01 elapsed. (3/0/0 errors)`
`done`
`Pass completed, 4 bad blocks found. (4/0/0 errors)`
`